# How to highlight an android recyclerview item at runtime

Tags: android-recyclerview, runtime, highlight

I have a mapview and a recyclerview in my fragment . the recyclerview display shops information and their location show with marker on the mapview . how can I  highlight a recyclerview item by clicking it’s marker on the mapview?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you provide any source code?

Comment: i used RecyclerView.scrollToPosition()  in mygooglemap.onmMarkerClickListener to move to clicked marker's item in recyclerview. but by now i don't know how to highlight that item.

Comment: EDIT your question and include there what have you tried. Try not posting comments to your own question, unless necessary.